# How to typecast values like (int) using zend engine API?

Tags: c, php-internals

What I've tried:

```
//...
zend_long dest;
if (UNEXPECTED(!zend_parse_arg_long(arg, &dest, NULL, 0, 0))) {
    zend_verify_arg_error(E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR, zf, arg_num, "be of the type integer", "", zend_zval_type_name(arg), "", arg);
}
zval_ptr_dtor(arg);
ZVAL_LONG(arg, dest);
//...
```

The problem is that if `arg` is a literal string with a malformed number like `"10x"` the engine raises a notice:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in...
```

What I really wanted is to be able to cast `arg` just like as the following PHP userland code:

```
(int) "10x" // evaluates to 10, no NOTICE
```

> I'm still crawling through the zend API so any help on how to find a good (updated) PHP internals reference or general advice is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform an integer cast without modifying the original value using the `zval_get_long` function:

```
zend_long lval = zval_get_long(zv);
```

If you want to change the type of an existing zval you can use the `convert_to_long` function:

```
convert_to_long(zv);
// Z_TYPE_P(zv) == IS_LONG now
```

If `zv` is a reference, `convert_to_long` will unwrap the reference before casting (so `zv` will no longer be a reference). It is more likely that you want to dereference it instead (so the reference is still there, but `zv` points to its inner value):

```
ZVAL_DEREF(zv);
convert_to_long(zv);
```

Note that in PHP 7 it is not necessary to perform a separation before using `convert_to_long`.

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared things up. Any good place with a good zend api reference? Official documentation seems very outdated and sparse.

Comment: @marcio You're a bit out of luck there right now, there isn't really any docs on the PHP 7 API yet. The closest is this migration info: https://wiki.php.net/phpng-upgrading Which is also not totally up to date ^^